# Android studio Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, expo

Good day all, I'm using expo react native for mobile app, I opened it in android studio to create an apk and I'm getting "Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#org.unimodules.core.AppLoader#react-native-headless@value value=(org.unimodules.adapters.react.apploader.RNHeadlessAppLoader) from [:unimodules-react-native-adapter] AndroidManifest.xml:14:13-88
> is also present at [:expo-modules-core] AndroidManifest.xml:14:13-86 value=(expo.modules.adapters.react.apploader.RNHeadlessAppLoader).
> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-14:91 to override."

Anyone know what I have to do to get past this error, which android:value I would have to change etc.

Comment: Have you considered using the EAS Build service to do your APK build so that you don't need to worry about problems of your own infrastructure being incompatible in some way with the requirements for a build (Android Studio, Java, Gradle, the operating system, the execution shell, yada-yada-yada) ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 :

I discovered that the Manifests cannot be combined because they have different SDK versions by using the gradle assemble -info command.

Everything restarted once I made the necessary changes to my build.gradle and Manifests files.

To be explicit, you must modify the AndroidManifest.xml's uses-sdk.

```
\uses-sdk /> android:targetSdkVersion="16" android:minSdkVersion="14"
```

The build's minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion for Android, in particular.

Gradle file :

```
android {
        compileSdkVersion 17
        buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"
    
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 16
        }
    }
```

Add this code in /android/build.gradle

```
subprojects {
  project.configurations.all {
      afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 26
                buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
            }
        }
    }
     resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
              && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
           details.useVersion "26.0.2"
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Solution 2 :

Try this link - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19239

Try this link - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33205